# Returning php callback in C#

Tags: c#, php, web-services, instagram

I am attempting to return a callback in a C# web service that was initiated by a PHP curl.  The callback url I specified in the PHP program was 'http://www.mywebpage/instagrampics/service1.asmx?op=getpics'.  What I want to do is subscribe to an Instagram subscription. Below is my C# web service.

```
      public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public MemoryStream getpics(string hubchallenge)
    {

         byte[] resultBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hubchallenge);

          return new MemoryStream(resultBytes);
 }
```

What the Instagram call is doing is sending the url as 'http://www.mywebpage/instagrampics/service1.asmx?op=getpics?hub.challenge=1234'

This gives me an error that says 'Method 'getpics?hub.challenge=1234' was not found in service Service1.  That is probably because the program expects an ampersand instead of a question mark to precede the callback value. Is my callback URL incorrect? Does anyone know how to return a callback in a C# web service to an Instagram call or is there another way of doing this.  I know I can do it easily in PHP but I can't figure out how to do it in C#.

Comment: I'm *pretty sure* `MemoryStream` is serializable.  Maybe return a `Byte[]` instead?

Comment: I'm pretty sure webmethod doesn't work on that way. Url/WebmethodName

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused on how C# calls webmethod.

Please take in consideration url/Webmethod-name and then vars

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: I tried using http://www.mywebpage/instagrampics/service1.asmx/getpics but that gave me an error saying the last slash was an error.  So I guess I don't know what is the proper url.

Comment: you are wainting also for some not optional vars. I think you must investigate more about webmethod and post or get with them

Comment: I am beginning to wonder if it is even possible to subscribe to Instagram using a C# web service.  I have done this using PHP with no problem.   Aren't there any Instagram C# users out there?